# XML getting the correct nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have two divs that I have created from the XML "Item" nodes #Option_Base-Shirt and #Option_Open-Main-Fabric-Collar. I want these two divs to be populated by "Sub" divs so the #Base-Shirt would have one sub div and #Option_Open-Main-Fabric-Collar would have two sub divs. At the moment each Item div has all three sub divs.

**XML**

```xml
<Item name="None" title="Base-Shirt" alt="jpg">
  <Sub name="Pique" title="Open-Main-Fabric-Collar" alt="png"></Sub>
</Item>

<Item name="Pique" title="Open-Main-Fabric-Collar" alt="png">
  <Sub name="Jersey" title="Outside-Pocket-Left" alt="png"></Sub>
  <Sub name="Main" title="Pocket" alt="png"></Sub>
</Item>
```

**Javascript**

```js
//Add Subs to Option div
$(document).find("Sub").each(function(){
  for (var i=0; i<=NumberItems; i++) {
    $("#Option_"+ItemNames[i])
      .append('<div class="Sub" id="' + $(this)
      .attr('title') +'"></div>');
  }
});
```

I think it should be something like this but this still puts all three divs in each item       div:

```
 //Add Subs to Option div
 $(document).find("Item").each(function(){
  for (var i=0; i<=NumberItems; i++) {
    $(this).find("Sub").each(function(){

            $("#Option_"+ItemNames[i]).append('<div class="Sub" id="' +   $(this).attr('title') +'"></div>');

    });
    }
});
```

Getting XML:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Load XML
$.ajax({
    url: 'data.xml',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parse,
    error: function(){alert("Error: Something wrong with XML");}
});

 function parse(document){

//Get all item names Var=ItemNames (Base_Shit, Collar...)
$(document).find("Item").each(function(){
```

Comment: And the problem / question is?

Comment: Where are you getting this XML from? From the use of `document`, it seems you have included jQuery in the XML file, or the XML in the document ?

Comment: The base-shirt div should have one sub div and the Open-Main-Fabric-Collar div should have two divs they both have three divs at the moment. Is there away you can do something like: $(document).find(item).children("Sub").each(function(){

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 // Load XML
 $.ajax({
  url: 'data.xml',
  dataType: "xml",
  success: parse,
  error: function(){alert("Error: Something wrong with XML");}
 });
  
function parse(document){

Comment: So you're using the word `document` as a variable name ?

Comment: Maybe I'm not doing this correctly but I'm using document to reference the XML

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work I place the function inside the function that I'm creating my item divs. Sorry I probably did not explain my question very well.

```
$(document).find("Item").each(function(){
    $(".Button").append('<div class="Item" id="' + $(this).attr('title') +'" name="' + $(this).attr('name') +'" alt="' + $(this).attr('alt') +'"><span>'+$(this).attr('title').replace(/\-/g, ' ')+'</span><div class="Fabric" id="Fabric_' + $(this).attr('title') +'"></div><div id="Option_' + $(this).attr('title') +'" class="Option"></div></div>');

    $(this).find("Sub").each(function(){
            $("#Option_"+$(this).parent().attr('title')).append('<div class="Sub" id="' + $(this).attr('title') +'"></div>');
    });


});
```